# Datatables Warning: Requested unknown parameter 0 for row 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

Iam creating a Datatable using jquery and I want to pass an array of data to populate the table data.

This is what I do:-

```
   var dataArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
            var temp = {};
            temp['east'] = data.Data[i]["east"];
            temp['west'] = data.Data[i]["west"];
            temp['north'] = data.Data[i]["north"];
            temp['south'] = data.Data[i]["south"];
            dataArray.push(temp);
        }

        $('#mDataTable').DataTable({ "columns": columnTitles, "data": dataArray });
```

But I get the following error:-

[image]

My array is an array with objects. How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is `columnTitles`?

Comment: As @markpsmith suggest, we need to see columntitles and the markup / HTML. This error is by 99.99999% caused by a mismatch between either data and the markup, or references in code to non-existing columns.